# HTML Formatting error with Bootstrap and Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Target]

[image: Current]

The first picture is the design I want to replicate, and the second picture is my current draft. I've been stuck on formatting issues for a long time now, and I'm hoping that someone from the community can help me.

As you can see from the second picture, there is some weird formatting error. I believe it might something related to the ng scope.

Here is my html code (with the css styles)

```
<style>
.index #contactsid-app-view 
  {
    background: url(/images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
      -moz-background-size: cover !important;
      -o-background-size: cover !important;
      background-size: cover !important;

  }
  .header{ display:none !important;}


  .navbar-inverse
  {
    background-color: #00003D; 
  }

.navbar .divider-vertical {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 9px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
  border-right-color: #222222;
  border-left-color: #111111;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
    display: none;
  }
}

</style>

<div class="container">
  <footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-text pull-left" id="footer-body">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY CONTENT</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="/images/hid-logo-print.png" style="width:100%; height:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6" style=" background-color: rgba(84, 177, 200, .76);
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #6cbdd4;
      ">
           <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/119424883" margin="5%" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" title="Introducing Humanitarian ID" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#login"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Logiin</span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#register"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>Register</span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-arrow btn-block" href="/#about"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span><span translate>About</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Background info: The web app uses Angular.js and Bootstrap